# What is the @inlinable attribute in Swift?

Tags: swift, compiler-optimization

I have more research about `@inlinable` functions but could not find any simple explanation.

```
@inlinable func printPlusOne(_ num: Int) {
    print("My number: \(num + 1)")
}
```

Usage shown above.

I find a topic for this attribute but i could not figure out. Can someone explain it simplify and what is benefit this attribute?

This is the link topic i read : https://swiftrocks.com/understanding-inlinable-in-swift

Thanks for replying.

Comment: I thought the link you included explained it well. @inlinable is meant for creators of libraries and frameworks. It allows the authors of such frameworks to mark functions as being able to be inlined (where the code of the function  is copied into the target instead of making a function call into your framework.) Inlining can give a speed boost because function calls take time to set up.

Comment: The bottom line: `@inline` and `@inlining` are advanced compiler directives, and if you don't understand what they are for, don't mess with them. It's like adjusting the profile of an engine's camshaft. If you know what you are doing you can get a performance boost, but you can also mess things up if you **don't** know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

From the Swift doc:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/attributes/#inlinable

> Apply this attribute to a function, method, computed property, subscript, convenience initializer, or deinitializer declaration to **expose that declaration’s implementation as part of the module’s public interface**.

→ When you use it, people will be able to see the source code of it. A bit like when you do a C++ implementation directly inside a header file. And the compiler **may (or not)** do something about it.

> Inlinable code **can’t interact with private or fileprivate symbols**.

→ That's to highlight when you can't use it.

As for the benefits, I would love to point to [the ISO C++ take on its equivalent keyword (inline)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions):

> (conceptually similar to what happens with a #define macro)
> This can, depending on a zillion other things, improve performance, because the optimizer can procedurally integrate the called code — optimize the called code into the caller.

> Do inline functions improve performance?
> Yes and no. Sometimes. Maybe.
> **There are no simple answers.** inline functions might make the code faster, they might make it slower. They might make the executable larger, they might make it smaller. They might cause thrashing, they might prevent thrashing. And they might be, and often are, totally irrelevant to speed.